# InfoWindow Android - Not Working

Tags: android, google-maps, infowindow, marker

I have a google Map v2 code in Android Studio, its showing the results from an json, this part works fine, when the user click in the marker it open a InfoWindow (OK) but Id like to insert an + (plus) button that will lead to other page with the details from the marker that the user tapped, I tried so many tutorials and they look depreciate. Someone could please help me on this please?

```
**Marker

mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, long)).title(nome_dentist).snippet(adress);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open the details view when the InfoWindow is clicked by adding an onClickListener on the InfoWindow, but since it is rendered as an image you can't add buttons to the InfoWindow. See the official documentaion: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows#info_window_events

Answer (score 0):

If google maps infowindow click not working then here is a quick fix

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;
    map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
}
```

and then

```
@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```